# What is the exact meaning of `pl.col("")` expression with empty string argument

Tags: python-polars

The example in a section about 'list context' in the [polars-book](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/list_context.html) uses `pl.col("")` expression with an empty string `""` as the argument.

```
# the percentage rank expression
rank_pct = pl.col("").rank(reverse=True) / pl.col("").count()
```

From the context and the output I can guess what `pl.col("")` expression does. But the API documentation does not seem to cover a case of empty string as the argument to `pl.col` and I would like to know the precise meaning in this use case. Any helpful answer is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The precise meaning is to act as a 'root' Expression to start a chain of Expressions inside a List context, i.e., inside `arr.eval(....)`.  I'll need to take a step back to explain...

##### 'Root' Expressions

In general, only certain types of Expressions are allowed to start (or be the 'root' of) an Expression.  These 'root' Expressions work with a particular context (`select`, `filter`,`with_column`, etc..) to identify what data is being addressed.

Some examples of root Expressions are `polars.col`, `polars.apply`, `polars.map`, `polars.first`, `polars.last`, `polars.all`, and `polars.any`.  (There are others.)

Once we declare a "root" Expression, we can then chain other, more-generic Expressions to perform work.  For example, `polars.col("my_col").sum().over('other_col').alias('name')`.

##### The List context

A List context is slightly different from most contexts.  In a List context, there is no ambiguity as to what data is being addressed.  There is only a list of data.  As such, `polars.col` and `polars.first` were chosen as "root" Expressions to use within a List context.

Normally, a `polars.col` root Expression contains information such as a string to denote a column name or a wildcard expression to denote multiple columns.  However, this is not needed in a List context.  There is only one option - the single list itself.

As such, any string provided to `polars.col` is ignored in a List context. For example, from the code from the Polars Guide, this code also works:

```py
# Notice that I'm referring to columns that do not exist...
rank_pct = pl.col("foo").rank(reverse=True) / pl.col("bar").count()
```

Since any string provided to a `polars.col` Expression will be ignored in a List context, a single empty string `""` is often supplied, just to prevent unnecessary clutter.

##### Edit: New `polars.element` expression

Polars now has a [`polars.element`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.element.html) expression designed for use in list evaluation contexts. Using `polars.element` is now considered idiomatic for list contexts, as it avoids confusion associated with using `col(“”)`.

Comment: `@cbilot` : Fantastic answer, thanks a lot! Adding it to the polars-book would help new users to wrap their heads around the concepts behind polars expressions.